# Android BroadcastReceiver Lifecycle: documentation wrong for dynamically registered receiver?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I define a `BatteryInfo extends BroadcastReceiver` class.  I call its constructor once in my `Activity onCreate()`.  I register it with `Activity.registerReceiver` in my `onCreate()`.

I am trying to figure out whether I need to unregister it and/or set its reference to `null` in order to allow my Activity to die without leaking memory or clogging up intent senders in the system, or whether the system gracefully tosses everything associated with this on its own.  Towards that end I am pondering the [BroadcastReceiver Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle) where I read:

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active."

what does this mean?  Obviously the object I have created with `new BatteryInfo()` and registered with `registerReceiver()` persists through the entire time my activity persists.  I log results from it and see them that entire time.  Obviously it has not become invalid after the first time its `onReceive()` was called.

I am wondering if this section of documentation perhaps applies only to `BroadcastReceivers` which are registered in the `AndroidManifest`?  And that it is simply incorrect or irrelevant to `BroadcastReceivers` that are dynamically created and registered?

And of course, I am wondering what is proper clean up and derferencing for my dynamic receivers.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do for `BroadcastReceivers` in code is register and unregister them.  That statement is to inform you that you can't do any work outside of the `onReceive`, for example in another thread, and return a value back to the `BroadcastReceiver`.  To do that you would get the `BroadcastReceiver` to start a `Service`.